# JQuery: How can I invoke click event from focus event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput">                         
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="fileinput"  hidden>
```

My Javascript is:

```
$('#textinput').on('focus', function () {

    console.log("focused");

    $('#fileinput').click();

});
```

So, you may know what I want to do, smart people.
I want to hide my one input (type="file") element and use another input (type="text") element to upload a file.

However, I cannot invoke a click event in focus event like the code above while I can still get "focused" message in the console.

Why can't I trigger click event inside focus event? (But I can trigger click event from another click event.)

Thank you for your future help!

Comment: $('#fileinput').trigger('click');

Comment: @DineshPatra `.click()` is shortcut  for `.trigger('click')`

Comment: @DineshPatra I tried but it did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Pranav C Balan, for letting me know the shortcut.

I have tried this. And it seems working for me. So I think there is some error in otherparts of your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput">                         
        <input type="file" id="fileinput" name="fileinput"  hidden>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#textinput').on('focus', function () {
                console.log("focused");
                $('#fileinput').click();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I want natural event popping up a file explorer... I do not need a new event just alerting a message...

Comment: I have updated the code, It is same code what you had written. This code works in google chrome, but it does not work in firefox.  I am researching on firefox.

Comment: Oh, it was the problem of Firefox. I tried with Chromium and it worked. Thank you!